# How to improve passive character builds?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

How can characters (D&D 5e) which have powerful passive/static abilities be improved to be more fun and dynamic during game play?

Consider an 8th-level Dwarven [Forge Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ForgeDomain) with:

- AC 24
- Fire/Poison/Cold resistance
- DC 17 spell save
- WIS 18
- [Warcaster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster)

These are good attributes, to be sure, yet actual game play with this character, especially in combat, is passive. His abilities are turned "on", and that's it. There are seemingly few mechanisms for creative interaction with enemies or the environment - the character's actions can easily be automated.

**There are just too few "Dude that was awesome!" moments for clerics, IME**

#### What Question is *Not* About

- Damage optimization
- Healing optimization
- Being the strongest tank in the party
- A way to use more than one concentration spell at a time

#### Example of Non-Passive Gameplay

- Using a familiar to remote-cast a spell
- Polymorphing into a creature to get around an obstacle (flying over something, swimming through a sea cave)
- Using illusions to affect enemy actions without requiring combat
- Using Misty Step or Teleport to bypass defenses or surprise an enemy
- Using Mage Hand to for Indiana Jones-style tricks of gathering precious items
- Using any number of battlefield control spells to alter the environment (Spike Growth, Fog Cloud, Entangle). *(Wall of Fire finally offers some of this to Forge Clerics, but as a 4th-level spell must be used sparingly).*

#### Passive Cleric Gameplay

- Stand alongside fighter/barbarian types with Aura of Vitality/Purity or Spirit Guardians. Usually with Spiritual Weapon or Sacred Flame each turn. Useful, yes, but becomes quite stale after a few sessions.
- Using Silence to stop an enemy mage from casting. Again, useful, but as it requires concentration, this prevents other useful spells from being used.
- Using [Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Help) action to give primary fighter advantage in combat. Great teamwork, but it's the same in any fight, and your turn is over in 3 seconds.

What are some options to make this type of powerful cleric (or similar class) more dynamic and fun to play vs. useful but "automatable" choices? Would additional feats help? A certain magical item? Multiclassing?

Comment: You are complaining about a lack of variety and you point to a barbarian as having more?  Your question puzzles me. I will ask if you expect to go up a level any time soon and, if the answer is yes, if multiclassing is an option at your table. - While I am at it, will you please list the cantrips you have, and list all of the spells that you usually have prepared. There should be 12 spells prepared plus 8 domain spells for a total of 20.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Good point re: barbarian, although I guess the sheer utility of that class in combat is self-justifying. You know what you're getting, and it hits hard in battle, and not so much (or at all) in other scenarios.

Comment: I'll list cantrips/spells here, since they're very specific, and I was hoping the question could potentially apply to other builds than the one I list. C: Guidance, Word of Radiance, Sacred Flame, Thaumaturgy. Typical Spells: Healing Word, Guiding Bolt, Prot. Good/Evil, Searing Smite, Heat Metal, Hold Person, Magic Weapon, Silence, Spiritual Weapon, Aura of Vitality, Dispel Magic, Elem. Weapon, Prot. from Energy, Revivify, Spirit Guardians, Banishment, Fabricate, Wall of Fire.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I would entirely accept answers which conclude "the class is fine, you're not fully utilizing it". I don't necessarily mean to blame the sub-domain here.

Comment: To clarify something you say "The most useful actions are to keep [concentration spell] up". Are you using an Action to concentrate on these spells, or was there some other meaning in this sentence?

Comment: @KamilDrakari I mostly meant that those two relatively passive spells supply (IMO) a tremendous amount of value. The entire group benefits, but it's not necessarily an interesting way of engaging with the content. There are exceptions, of course, using Spirit Guardians during a flying encounter was a fun way to slow enemies enough to be manageable. I'd _also_ say that the vast majority of spells for cleric require concentration, which does create this agonizing cost-benefit calculation, on top of the choice of which spells to prepare after rest.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This question needs a goal with their play in mind before we can give meaningful answer instead of just more fun and variety. Clerics get a lot of prepared spells and know all of their spells, you can always switch out your kit. Are you considering it a lacking kit because you're worried about damage optimization? If so, you will have problems because the best option is usually *the* best option in 5e. If you are always making this choice to pick the best option each turn, you are not using the other spells in your kit. To address fun, we need a better understanding of what you find fun.

Comment: Have you played other classes in D&D 5e that didn't have this problem? What made them feel better to you? Have you tried other RPG's (either similar systems such as Pathfinder or completely different ones such as FATE)?

Comment: This question sounds like *"How to make passive build more active, but keep it passive?"* It's hard for me to imagine an answer that could be satisfactory

Comment: @Mołot Can you explain your characterization of the question? I find your comment somewhat condtradictory.

Answer (score 8):

There are 3 basic roles in any cooperative multiplayer game; offense (a.k.a. damage dealer), support, and defense (a.k.a. tank). In small groups, it is often necessary for a single player to take on multiple roles. The problem with this is that a generalist will **always** perform worse than a specialist in whatever task the specialist is an expert in. Your party has more than enough people that everyone could specialize in one role. However, you appear to have built a generalist. This means that for any given task, someone else in the party will be better at doing it than you.

Most of your spells are offensive, with a couple support spells that are useful in combat (Healing Word, Aura of Vitality, Dispel Magic). That is a pretty good template for a battle mage type of build. But then we have a bunch of defensive spells (Protection from Good and Evil, Protection from Energy, Spirit Guardians) and pure utility spells that are very rarely used in the middle of combat (Silence, Revivify, Fabricate).

It also appears like you are having trouble deciding if you want to fight at range or in melee. Cleric can certainly do either, but trying to do both is more generalization that you don't need. The vast majority of your offensive spells are ranged, so you seem to be leaning in that direction. However, you have 3 different concentration spells that all improve your melee damage, but by different amounts (Searing Smite, Magic Weapon, and Elemental Weapon). That signals to me that you want to be ready to get into melee regardless if you are in a major or minor encounter.

I would recommend dropping most of your spells that are not ranged offensive or support. Of these, I would keep one or two of the most powerful to act as your ace in the hole, such as Revivify and Spirit Guardians. You already have a lot of ranged attacks, so I would take more support spells. No one will complain if you get more healing spells, but if you find that a little boring I would look into support spells that focus on debuffing the enemy (Bane, Command, or Blindness/Deafness).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question to clarify what I'm really asking, which isn't about damage (or healing) output, it's about having something "to do" on your turn, vs. just "being there". I do think Blindness/Deafness is prob. something I don't use enough, so thanks for bringing that up. Bane and Bless are tough as their concentration requirement prevents usage of Auras, Spirit Guardians, Heat Metal, etc.

Comment: @Dan1701 edits that invalidate current answers are generally not welcomed here. That said, your question is currently closed so you will have to edit it substantially anyway.